# What happened to the old reputation graph?

Tags: discussion, reputation

Awhile back the reputation used to be displayed by a line graph, not its a bar graph does the old reputation graph exist? Or has it been superseded?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every user has a Network Profile. They've put the graph there.

To see your graph, in your user page click on [Network Profile](http://stackexchange.com/users/e509bf02-6c21-4bad-a298-74ba8a748762). Then click the [reputation tab](http://stackexchange.com/users/e509bf02-6c21-4bad-a298-74ba8a748762?tab=reputation)

**Edit**

See the official annouce: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/04/stack-exchange-network-profiles/

Comment: well, that link gets me to *your* Network profile. where do click on the page to get that?

Comment: @JustJeff, thanks. I'll check because it works for me. And I've added the network profiles official announcement. See again my answer.

Comment: @just the link to the network profile is on your user page

Comment: got it now, thanks guys. fwiw, i think i missed it b/c my monitor/viewing-angle did a less than stellar job at providing contrast with the fg/bg colors in that area.